# Custom permalink in Wordpress - removing part of URL

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

If I create a new site in WP the permalink becomes https://www.example.com/base/postname. This is because when I log in, I use https://www.example.com/base/wp-admin.

But is there any way for me to create a site without /base/ part?

Comment: one thing, move all the files to the root folder not sub folder base

Comment: may this url is useful http://askwpgirl.com/move-wordpress-subdomain-root/

Comment: Thank you! Will test on development server and say if it works or not

Comment: @easyquestions Did you check my code, by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. Eventhough I think that it might be the correct solution, it doesn't work for me. My site is built partly on wp, and most of it custom, which I think make it mess up. The whole situation gives me a headache. I also tried to change the /base/ to something different, e.g /notbase/, but then the former pages and articles didn't update, and went unacessable (I tried to update my permalinks). So I'm kind of lost now.

Answer (score 0):

Move your WordPress site to the root folder and after you can set below things.

### Method-1 | wp-config.php

Add these two lines to your **`wp-config.php`**, where **"example.com"** is the correct location of your site

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

---

### Method-2 | functions.php

Add these two lines to your **`functions.php`**.

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://example.com' );
```

> **Note:** This settings should include the `http://` part and should not have a slash `"/"` at the end.